# How to aggregate data with d3.js for a BarChart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, observable

I have been trying to make a bar chart where I present data from a data set that has several ocurrences of years. I want to show the year in axis X and on axis Y show the number of occurrences of every year. I have been trying the following code on Observable, but I am not sure why it is not working. I tried checking other S.O. posts but couldnt succeed.

[image]

Comment: Try "let" instead "var"

Comment: Oh I tried it before, it says that the word let is reserved

Comment: which d3.js version are you using?

Comment: It should be the last version as I am importing the BarChart in Observable. I am importing like: import {BarChart} from "@d3/horizontal-bar-chart"

Comment: Did you tried to move the import line to the top of codes? first line. Maybe is not declared first and used after!?

Comment: Observable takes the import regardless of where it is located

Comment: Then try to place the "var" outside of the chart

Comment: Ssays: Syntax Error unexpected token.

Comment: Move all purple code outside the chart

Comment: I moved it outside and it still gives a SyntaxError: Unexpected keyword 'var' I am not sure why the var or let is a problem

Comment: The problem is that Barchart is a function, which expects values as parameters! On your image the code which is in the purple is not in the right place, move up, outside the Barchart function. The Barchart function allows just parameters and not even codes

Comment: As @akicside mentioned: you were trying to declare a variable within an object literal. This is not valid JavaScript code. Object literals only allow key-value pairs, separated by commas. Place the selected code _before_ before your `BarChart()` call.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for joining. I just updated my screenshot so that you guys could see. It still gives me problems, I think its dirrent now but I am not sure why it says that there is an unexpected token. I also tried removing the var keyword but it still does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues going on here that largely stem from the fact that you are working within an [Observable notebook](https://observablehq.com/), rather than a vanilla Javascript environment. I think it's worth taking a good look at [Learning Observable](https://observablehq.com/@observablehq/learning-observable-introduction) to make sure you understand the basics.

In particular, you can't type:

```
let x = 1
let y = 2
```

into a single cell. This is effectively what you're trying to do in your main cell that defines the chart and you get a syntax error. What you might do instead is type:

```
x = 1
```

into one cell and then

```
y = 2
```

into a different cell. You could then reference those values in other cells.

You also might combine things like:

```
x_plus_y = {
  let x = 1;
  let y = 2;
  return x+y;
}
```

The value of `x_plus_y` would then be available for use in other cells.

---

Now, I suppose what you're trying to create a count by year of astronaut missions using https://think.cs.vt.edu/corgis/csv/astronauts/.

Assuming so, [this Observable Notebook](https://observablehq.com/d/3b4b3f50a7cff2a3) shows a couple of ways to accomplish this.

Finally, I think that it is a mistake to use the `BarChart` component as you are trying to do. That component was really more of an experimental stepping stone to their more complete, higher level plotting library called [Observable Plot](https://observablehq.com/@observablehq/plot). I think it's much easier to get where you want with Plot and you have more control. It' also easy to use Plot in a vanilla environment, like so:

```js
let div = d3.select('#plot')
fetch(
  "https://think.cs.vt.edu/corgis/datasets/csv/astronauts/astronauts.csv"
).then(async function (r) {
  let astronauts = d3.csvParse(await r.text(), d3.autoType);
  div.append(() => Plot.plot({
    y: {
      grid: true
    },
    x: { tickFormat: (y) => (y % 10 == 0 ? d3.format('d')(y) : "") },
    marks: [
      Plot.barY(astronauts, Plot.groupX({ y: "count" }, { x: "Mission.Year" })),
      Plot.ruleY([0])
    ]
  }))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3@7"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@observablehq/plot@0.6"></script>
<div id="plot"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your guidance and suggestions Dr. McClure :)